# How can I run several independent jobs using one bash script?

Tags: bash, slurm

I have several independent jobs that I want to run simultaneously on a computer node.

I want to run each job using only one core of the requested node. How can I write a bash script to do this?

This is the bash script that I wrote but didn't work

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --job-name=20
#SBATCH --partition=the_partition
#SBATCH --nodes=1
#SBATCH --ntasks=20
for n in {1..20};
do
cd "dictionary$n"
./ the job
done
```

How can I modify the script to run the 20 independent jobs simutanuously?

Comment: Replace `./ the job` with `./ the job & cd ..`?

Comment: Start jobs in the background

Comment: As Cyrus says, put an `&` at the end of the `./ the job` line. If you want to wait for all the jobs to finish, add a line `wait` at the end of the script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution is with a job array:

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --job-name=20
#SBATCH --partition=the_partition
#SBATCH --nodes=1
#SBATCH --ntasks=1
#SBATCH --array=1-20
cd "dictionary$SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID"
./ the job
```

The above script will create a job array with 20 jobs, and each job will `cd` to the directory based on the `$SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID` variable, that will take a different value between 1 and 20 for each job in the array.